# Datatables data from var array

Tags: javascript, arrays, datatable

I have a array data in var price like this:

```
[0: Object { Moda: "A", Service: "B", Price: "1", … },1: Object { Moda: "C", Service: "D", Price: "2", … }]
```

How to call and show it at datatables columns?

Here datatable script:

```
$('#table').DataTable({
  "data": price,
  "columns": [{
      "data": "Moda"
    },
    {
      "data": "Service"
    },
    {
      "data": "Price"
    },
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the array of objects via aaData property, then use column property to define which column should recieve which data:

```js
var jsonArray = [{ Moda: "A", Service: "B", Price: "1"}, { Moda: "C", Service: "D", Price: "2"}];



$('#example').dataTable({
    "bAutoWidth" : false,
    "aaData" : jsonArray,
    "aoColumns" : [ {
        "data" : "Moda"
    }, {
        "data" : "Service"
    }, {
        "data" : "Price"
    } ]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>Moda</th>
             <th>Service</th>
             <th>Price</th>
         </tr>
        </thead>
 </table>
```

Comment: i actually get this data `[0: Object { Moda: "A", Service: "B", Price: "1", … },1: Object { Moda: "C", Service: "D", Price: "2", … }]` array from request to server , how to make my array can be like your `var jsonArray` ?

Comment: Your array is same as `jsonArray`, if you `console.log` the `jsonArray`, it will look like your array, `0` showing position of element in array and `object` showing datatype of that element.

Comment: its a little bit diffrent if i `console.log` the `jsonArray` will show `Array [ {…}, {…} ]` and my array only show `Array []` , but it has same amount data

Comment: If you expand the `jsonArray`, then you will get it, don't know why you are getting empty array. Did you got response from from server?

Comment: i can show your `jsonArray` data to my table,  but i dont know why my array cant show

Comment: i get the response , i use multiple request from server and use  `data.push(...data.data)` to merged the data

Comment: I think your data table code execute before you getting data, make sure that the variable you passing in datatable should contains data.